# Add cors to this snippet to allow all origins

Tags: reactjs, cors

I need to add cors to this snippet to allow any origin The server.js runs as a node server on localhost:8000 and my rails app is running on localhost:3000 Can someone please show me how to add cors to this snippet It's different from examples I've seen because the connection is made by io in the script instead of app as in examples

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socket = require("socket.io");
const io = socket(server);

const users = {};

const socketToRoom = {};

io.on('connection', socket => {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/

Comment: Still getting the error cross origin request blocked

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    next();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that io makes the connection to httpServer, not app ?

Comment: To better answer that I'll need to see the actual error you're getting.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NfMMOFk. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: You have "reactjs" in the tags. Was it a React application that reported this error? Do you have ` "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` in your package.json?